# One to one function between [0,1] and [0,2]: How to prove or disprove?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Recall that for $a,b$ an element of the set of real numbers and $a<b$, the closed interval $[a,b]$ in real numbers is defined by $[a,b]=\{x$ is an element of reals|$a\leq x\leq b\}$. Show that the given intervals have the same cardinality by giving a formula for a one to one function $f$ mapping the first interval onto the second:

$[0,1] \to [0,2]$

So I understand that in order to show a function is one to one you need to show that the two sets have a one to one correspondence. How would you show this in a formal proof? I can only think of lining up the numbers in each set...

Comment: A function can be one-to-one without necessarily being a one-to-one correspondence. Of course, if a function is a one-to-one correspondence, then it is one-to-one (and onto).

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135461/change-of-coordinate-codomain-from-1-1-to-0-1

Answer (score 4):

In the particular case of two closed intervals a bijection $[a,b]\to[c,d]$ easy to find is$$x\mapsto c+\frac{x-a}{b-a}(d-c)$$which "rescale" $[a,b]$ onto $[c,d]$.

A bijective function is a [one-to-one correspondence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bijection), since it is both an [injective, i.e. one-to-one, function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_function) and a [surjective](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surjective_function) one.